# Will all my Stack Exchange accounts be inaccessible when MyOpenID shuts down>

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

I use OpenID to log in to all my Stack Exchange accounts. If my OpenID provider ever shuts down, will my profiles be inaccessible? Will I have to register new accounts, thus losing all my reputation, badges and favorites?

Comment: Since you know its closing down, why not switch providers?

Comment: I think what he's asking is will he basically have to register a new account, thus losing any rep he's gained on various Stack sites with his existing one?

Comment: Yes, that is my concern. I didn't find an option in the account settings of stackexchange to change the way I log in. I always have to click on "use openid".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to your user profile and click on "my logins" to link another auth provider to your account:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Relevant help center pages:

[Why do I see the message “OpenId endpoint not found” when I try to log in?](https://superuser.com/help/openid-endpoint)

> If you cannot log into your OpenID provider, or if you know your provider has ceased supporting an OpenID, please create a new account and then contact us to request an account merge.

Still, it's better to prevent problems if you know this will happen, so…

[How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://superuser.com/help/edit-credentials)

> **Please Note: MyOpenID is no longer actively supported by Janrain. If your only login for your Stack Exchange account is MyOpenID, we suggest that you add a backup login method, as any outages in MyOpenID could lock you out of your Stack Exchange account.**
>
> Adding additional logins to your account is useful because it provides a way to access your account in case you lose your password. You can choose Google, Facebook, Yahoo!, and other popular OpenID providers; create a new Stack Exchange OpenID by providing your email address and creating a password; or you can manually enter another OpenID address.

Note that [account recovery](https://superuser.com/help/reset-password) does not work with external OpenID providers.

Comment: "by Janrain"???????????????

Comment: @Braiam That's who runs (ran?) MyOpenID. [myOpenID™ and the myOpenID™ website are trademarks of Janrain, Inc.](https://www.myopenid.com/)

Comment: Ok, I understood the help page meant "January" :(